# Complexity of a variant of #Positive-2-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, complexity-classes, counting

***#Positive-2SAT*** is the problem of counting the number of satisfying assignments to a given Positive 2-CNF formula i.e 2-CNF formulas in which each literal is a positive occurrence of a variable.

The following variant of *#Positive 2-SAT* is defined as follows :

For example ,We are given a set of variables :

**(a,b,c,d,e)**

The set of all possible *positive 2-literal clauses* from the given set of variables are :

- **A = [ ab ,ac ,ad ,ae ]**
- **B = [ bc ,bd ,be ]**
- **C = [ cd ,ce ]**
- **D = [ de ]**

This version of problem puts restrictions on the inputs such that we can only choose at max only two clause from each set mentioned above to form our set of input clauses.

Ex-

1. A valid input to this variant of *#Positive 2-SAT* would be ***(ab ,ac ,bc ,cd)*** here we have
   only at max 2 clauses form each set mentioned above.
2. An invalid input to this variant of *#Positive 2-SAT* would be ***(ac ,ad ,ae ,bc ,cd)*** this
   is invalid as we have chosen more than 2 clauses from *set A*, mentioned
   above, thus its not a valid input to this version of the problem as we must only choose at max 2 clause form each set.

If its #P-complete for 2-clauses per set at max ,then is the result also true for 1-clause per set at max?

> Motivation behind this is to see how the number of solutions changes
> with respect to the overlap between clauses ,thus I want to know if
> its *#p-complete even for 2-clauses per set* ,this will make it easier
> to see the relation.

We know from this [post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/14535/67865) that this variant is #P-complete where we can select at max only 3-clauses from each set mentioned above ,that's why I wanted to know if this is #P-complete where we allowed to select at max only 2 clauses from each set.

Is this variant of *#Positive-2-SAT* *#P-complete*?

Edit :

To clarify Steven confusion ,The sets are just a special way to classify the set of all possible positive-2-literal clauses with respect to k variables ,and my restriction is that we can make a set of 2-literal clauses as our input to the #Positive-2-SAT but we  choose clauses from each set but we may not choose more than 3-clauses from any of these sets.

And any current answer doesn't resolve my question as they seem have to misunderstood the problem statement.

Comment: Sounds like a very weird restriction on the inputs. What's the motivation?

Comment: Motivation behind this is to see how the number of solutions changes with respect to the overlap between clauses ,thus I want to know if we its #p-complete even for 2-clauses per set ,this will make it easier to see the relation.

Comment: Well, somewhat. It's not clear to me how this restriction bounds "overlap between clauses", since some elements can still appear a linear number of times.

Comment: this restriction makes it easier for me to reason about overlappings between clauses

Comment: @Dmitry yes the number of times a variables can appear in this restriction is not fixed ,but that doesn't matter when reasoning about overlapping between clauses with this kind of restriction

Comment: Looks like you can have a formula whose primal graph is a grid: order variables from left to right and top to bottom and each clause associated to variable $x$ is $x \vee r(x)$ and $x \vee b(x)$ where $r(x)$ is the variable on the right of $x$ and $b(x)$ the variable below $x$. To me, this sounds like the problem is likely #P-complete.

Comment: @holf Sorry ,but I don't understand you argument .

Comment: This is not an argument, just an observation. Let $G_{n,m}$ be an $n\times m$ grid. It naturally induces a monotone 2-SAT formula $F_{n,m}$ where each edge is a clause. I claim that for any $n,m$, $F_{n,m}$ is in the class of formulas you consider. And usually, grid smells bad because you could encode many thing into this. So it sets my intuition on "this is still #P-complete". Now I do not have a full fleshed proof nor the time right now to think more about it but this may help you.

Comment: @holf well ,I understand what you're saying but that the question is still ,can we prove that for any n,m, F_{n,m} is in the class of formulas with the restriction i mentioned in the question

Comment: Yes and I gave the proof, but to do that formally, I need to formalize the definition you did not bothered to write down: a formula is in the Anuj-class iff variables are ordered by $<$ and for every $x$, there are at most $2$ clauses from $C(x)$ where $C(x) = \{(x,y) \mid x<y\}$. Now if the grid is ordered as $y_{i,j} < y_{k,l}$ iff $i<k$ or ($i=k$ and $j<l$) then edges $(y_{i,j}, y_{i,j+1})$ and $(y_{i,j}, y_{i+1,j})$ in $C(y_{i,j})$ and they are the only one there, so this is indeed in the class you (did not) define.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146660/discussion-between-anuj-and-holf).

Comment: @holf I was very informal in my framing of the problem I thought it'd be more easier and more general to describe it in informal manner and also I haven't written it down formally myself .

Comment: @holf I understand you argument till the point where you formally define my input restriction but after that I didn't understand how you show that #monotone 2-SAT can be expressed under the those restriction on inputs

Comment: It makes no sense for the set $S$ of allowable literals to be part of the input of your problem along with the 2-SAT formula $\phi$. Once you are given $\phi$,  $S$ plays no role (or, if you wish, you can find a valid $S$ for any $\phi$). If $S$ is a parameter of the problem then it's unclear what you're asking: each instantiation of the problem only admits a finite number of input formulas $\phi$ and can be solved in constant time.  Can you define your problem precisely? What is part of the input and what is part of the problem? A formal definition of the set of input instances would help.

Comment: The question makes no sense.  In one place it says "at max only two clause from each set".  In another it says "we may not choose more than 3-clauses from any of these sets".  Also, the question still has the problem Steven points out of not explaining whether the sets are part of the input or part of the parameter of the problem, and not giving a clearly specified problem statement (it's not clear what formulas are allowed vs aren't allowed).  Any community votes on whether to close or keep this open?

Comment: Please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: @D.W I'll revise the whole post to clear the confusion.

Comment: @D.W Also ,the "we may not choose more than 3-clauses from any of these sets" is a different problem that is known to be #P-complete ,that's why I want to know if "at max only two clause from each set" which is a subset of #P-complete problem is #P-complete or not

Comment: In the future I hope you will take more care to write clearly and precisely from the very first version, so people don't waste your time or their time writing answers that aren't useful to you.  I notice that this seems to be a recurring issue; and that it seems like people have given similar feedback in the past but the issues continue to appear in future posts.

Comment: @D.W Sorry but ,isn't it subjective as to how one interpret a post ,in my defense ,I mentioned all the relevant details with proper formatting and examples too ,also included caveats to make it more clear.

Comment: but i understand what you are saying that why editing is given to clear any kind of confusion that is new to the person asking the question

Comment: It would be more helpful to [edit] your post based on the feedback given here, before engaging in discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous, as [Steven has indicated](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160621/complexity-of-a-variant-of-positive-2-sat/160824?noredirect=1#comment336533_160621).

One possible interpretation is that there is one set per variable, or in other words, each variable can occur in only two clauses.  This is unlikely to be $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete, as indicated below.

Another possible intepretation is that there can be any number of sets, from 0 to the number of variables, and the sets are provided as part of the input, and the only restriction is that the formula must be consistent with the provided sets.  In this case, the problem is $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete, as indicated below.

## One set per variable

Assuming you have one set per variable, it can be solved in polynomial time.

Form an undirected graph with one vertex per variable and one edge per clause.  Then there are at most two edges incident on each variable, i.e., each vertex has degree at most 2.  This graph splits into a disjoint set of components, where each component is a simple cycle, a simple path, or an isolated vertice.  For each component, you can count the number of satisfying assignments for that component (i.e., number of ways to assign values to the variables involved in that component) in polynomial time, then multiply them to get the total number of satisfying assignments for the original formula.

I leave it to you as a straightforward exercise describe a polynomial-time algorithm to count the number of satisfying assignments for an isolated vertex (hint: 2), for a simple path, and for a simple cycle.  A simple path corresponds to a formula of the form

$$(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (x_2 \lor x_3) \land \dots \land (x_{k-1} \lor x_k),$$

and a simple cycle corresponds to a formula of the form

$$(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (x_2 \lor x_3) \land \dots \land (x_{k-1} \lor x_k) \land (x_k \lor x_1).$$

It is believed that $\mathsf{P} \ne \#\mathsf{P}$.  Therefore, it is unlikely that this problem is $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete.

## Any number of sets

In this case, one special case is where there are zero sets.  This means that there are no restrictions on the formula, except that it must be a positive 2CNF formula.

It is known that counting the number of satisfying assignments to a positive 2CNF formula is $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete.  If a special case of the problem is $\#\mathsf{P}$-hard, then the general problem must be $\#\mathsf{P}$-hard as well.  It follows that your problem is $\#\mathsf{P}$-hard.

Also, it is easy to see that your problem is in $\#\mathsf{P}$.

It follows that your problem is $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit pedantic, but $\mathsf{P}$ is a class of decision problems, and the problem described is not a decision problem (therefore cannot be in $\mathsf{P}$.

Comment: "Where each component is a simple cycle, a simple path, or an isolated vertice" - I don't see why. In the example from the statement, it's possible to have clauses $ae,be,ce,de$, which means that $e$ has $4$ neighbors.

Comment: @Dmitry, good point!  I misunderstood the problem statement.  On looking again, I think the problem statement is ambiguous.  See my revised answer.  Hopefully this addresses your feedback now.

Comment: @Nathaniel, thank you!  I've revised my answer to correct this mistake.

Comment: @D.W  It seems you've misunderstood the problem statement ,I've edited the post to explain the confusion ,if its still not clear ,let me know.